# Intel 7265D wireless driver/firmware ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, intel, 16.04

How do I make *Intel 7265D wireless firmeware/driver* to work on *Ubuntu 16.04*? There is no network when I live boot into *Ubuntu 16.04* & `dmesg` reported this:

```
Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
```

Which means that I am running *Intel 7265D wifi firmware*. I have tried the instructions from below link, but no luck yet:

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

Any help please?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note, when you install 16.04, 7265D works for me without issues. I cam across this question when trying to get it updated to -21.ucode

```
[  142.519645] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210

modinfo iwlwifi | grep 7265D
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
```